# While loop in thread seems to not be running

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have been working on a little project with two threads.
One generates content and places it in a Queue (in a static context).
The other thread runs and waits for content in the queue to do something.

The Issue:

While the second thread is waiting for something to be placed in the queue, it seems to not be running, I will try to show this.

I am just curious is what is happening here.

`_slices` is a Queue : `Queue<E> _slices = new LinkedList<E>();`

Thread 2 `run()`:

```
while ( true ) {
    if ( !Main._slices.isEmpty() ) {
            System.out.println( "Something in the Queue!" );
       } else if ( Main.doneQueuing ) {
            break;
       }
}
```

This code above will not do anything once an element is added to the queue.

---

Now, this code works:

```
while ( true ) {
    System.out.println( "As long as a process is done here it works" );
    if ( !Main._slices.isEmpty() ) {
            System.out.println( "Something in the Queue!" );
       } else if ( Main.doneQueuing ) {
            break;
       }
}
```

Comment: That means queue is not getting populated. Check the code that populates the queue and make sure both queue references point to the same queue instance.

Comment: What is the type of `_slices`?

Comment: @AniketThakur The Queue has nothing to do with this, as I said above, there is a case that works.

Comment: @nosid it is the Queue

Comment: What I mean was queue `_slices` is always empty. Hence code flow never enters `if` statement. Hence check the code that fills up this queue.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell: _Queue_ is only an _interface_. What is the actual type you are using?

Comment: @AniketThakur The Queues stars empty, and after the Thread is running, and element is added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided information, I can only guess. I imagine your code looks as follows. The data structure `_slices` is shared between threads, there is a method *push* that adds an element to the shared data structure and is executed in one thread. And there is a method *poll* that checks if the data structure is not empty, and is executed in another thread.

```
class Foo {
    Queue<String> _slices = new ArrayDeque<>();
    void push(String element) {
        _slices.add(element);
    }
    void poll() {
        while (!_slices.empty()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, there is a so-called *data race*. That means the Java Programming Language does not guarantee, that executions are sequentially consistent. There are still some guarantees. However, they are quite complicated.

In order to avoid the *data race*, you should use a data structure that supports concurrency, e.g. *ConcurrentLinkedQueue* or *LinkedBlockingQueue*. Or you should use some synchronization mechanisms in your code, e.g. *synchronized* blocks.

Comment: But why does the dependent thread recognize that an element was added (size is no longer 0) if there is a process (like a println) before the if statement.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell: Because there is also some synchronization within _println_. That doesn't remove the _data race_. However, it changes the probability of the _race condition_.

Comment: I think this is a little over my current understanding. I will just go with your proposition. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList in not thread safe. You have to do **locking** your self.

Let's try [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) or [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)